# What is the adjectival form of "Plato"?

Tags: adjectives

What is the adjectival form of Plato?  "Platonistic"?  For example, in the following sentence:

> He made the Platonistic statement that there are truths, but there is
>   also the Truth.

Or is it incorrect to turn a proper noun into an adjective?

Comment: OED does also list ***Platonesque, Platonian, Platonical*** and ***Platonistic*** as valid adjectival forms, but relatively speaking...

Comment: [...they all have negligible currency](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Platonesque%2CPlatonian%2CPlatonical%2CPlatonistic%2CPlatonic&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CPlatonian%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BPlatonian%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bplatonian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CPlatonical%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BPlatonical%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bplatonical%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CPlatonistic%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BPlatonistic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bplatonistic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CPlatonic%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BPlatonic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bplatonic%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I feel like you knew the answer to this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for

***[Platonic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/platonic)***:

> - of, relating to, or characteristic of Plato or his doctrines:
>     the Platonic philosophy of ideal forms.

(Dictionary.reference.com)

- *Platonistic*:  (adjective) rare:

> - pertaining to or characteristic of or in accordance with [Platonism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Platonism).

Comment: :)- I would say, spot on.

Answer (score 7):

[**Platonic**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/platonic) -**proper adjective**

- of, relating to, or characteristic of Plato or his doctrines.

  - the [Platonic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/platonic) philosophy of ideal forms.

(This word platonic refers to the writings of Plato, an ancient Greek philosopher who wrote on the interesting subject of love- [vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/platonic))

- If Shakespeare is the proper noun, Shakespearian is the proper
  adjective.

> **Edit**: In English orthography, most proper nouns are capitalized, while
>   most common nouns are not.  **[English adjectives that derive from proper
>   nouns are usually capitalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_adjective)**. These two things, taken together, have
>   led to the creation of the lay terms "proper adjective" and "common
>   adjective" with meanings analogous to the lay meanings of "proper
>   noun" and "common noun". 
>   [Proper adjectives are just capitalized
>   adjectives.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_adjective) (wiki)

Comment: I think I see "platonic" uncapitalized when it means a non-sexual relationship with someone, but "Platonic", capitalized, when it refers to a philosophy of mathematics followed by Platonists, holding that mathematical objects exist in the world independently of whether they have yet been discovered by mathematicians.